# People answering me "what's new" when I ask them "How are you doing"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Pretty self explanatory. I'll ask someone "How are you doing?" and they will litteraly answer by saying *what* they are doing, as though I asked "What's up?", which confuses me. also happens very often, either when chatting or talking to someone face to face. Being a native french speaker, I was wondering if I got the meaning of the sentence wrong.

Comment: "How are you doing" is effectively a fixed phrase; it's a phatic salutation, and it invites fixed, phatic responses. It's better to understand it as an opaque symbol (the phrase as a whole), a way of saying "hello", and not try to predict how people will respond based on the meanings of the individual words.  If you really are specifically interested in how someone is doing, you'll do better by using a less hackneyed phrasing.

Comment: There are two types of salutation - mere greetings and conversation openers. Greetings invite, and expect, no more than a greeting in return. Conversation openers are inviting, and expecting, a considered and courteous response.